# NameError : name "a" is not defined

Tags: python, calculator, nameerror

I have made a simple calculator.py program in Python, but the program fails with NameError: "a" is not defined.

How can I fix  it?

```
import math
def control(a, x, y, z, k):
    return {
        'ADDITION': addition(x, y),
        'SUBTRACTION': subtraction(x, y),
        'MULTIPLICATION': multiplication(x, y),
        'DIVISION': division(x, y),
        'MOD': modulo(x, y),
        'SECONDPOWER': secondPower(x),
        'POWER': power(x, y),
        'SECONDRADIX': secondRadix(x),
        'MAGIC': magic(x, y, z, k)
    }[a]
def addition(x, y):
    return float(x) + float(y)
def subtraction(x, y):
    return float(x) - float(y)
def multiplication(x, y):
    return float(x) * float(y)
def division(x, y):
    return float(x) / float(y)
def modulo(x, y):
    return float(x) % float(y)
def secondPower(x):
    return math.pow(float(x),2.0)
def power(x, y):
    return math.pow(float(x),float(y))
def secondRadix(x):
    return math.sqrt(float(x))
def magic(x, y, z, k):
    l = float(x) + float(k)
    m = float(y) + float(z)
    return (l / m) + 1.0
try:
    control(a, x, y, z, k)
except ValueError:
    print("This operation is not supported for given input parameters")
out = control(a, x, y, z, k)
print(out)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    control(a, x, y, z, k)
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because before you run control in the try loop, you've never assigned 'a' to anything. Try assigning something to 'a' right before running control.

```
try:
    control(a, x, y, z, k)
```

Comment: So then you'd just want to do:

`try:
    a = input()
    control(a, x, y, z, k)`

That way, 'a' is initialized before you run the control function.

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign values not just to the variable **a** but also to other variables **x**, **y**, **z**, and **k** which you're passing here  -> control(a, x, y, z, k)

```
# for example:
a= 'ADDITION'
x= 1
y= 2
z=3
k=4
# and then you can call the function
control(a, x, y, z, k)
```

and the value of the variable **a** must be one of these(as you've defined)

```
'ADDITION'
'SUBTRACTION'
'MULTIPLICATION'
'DIVISION'
'MOD'
'SECONDPOWER'
'POWER'
'SECONDRADIX'
'MAGIC'
```

any other value of **a** will through a "KeyError"

Answer (score 0):

Your code fails in spite of existing `try/except` clause which should catch and handle errors because you have in the `except` clause only handling of the `ValueError`. The consequence of it is, that the `try/except` can raise an Error in case an other than `ValueError` error occurs.

You can change the `try/except` block as in the code below to catch all of the possible errors. Un-comment one by one only one line in `try:` to see a demonstration of handling for all of the possible error cases by the try/except clause:

```
import math
def control(a, x, y, z, k):
    return {
        'ADDITION': addition(x, y),
        'SUBTRACTION': subtraction(x, y),
        'MULTIPLICATION': multiplication(x, y),
        'DIVISION': division(x, y),
        'MOD': modulo(x, y),
        'SECONDPOWER': secondPower(x),
        'POWER': power(x, y),
        'SECONDRADIX': secondRadix(x),
        'MAGIC': magic(x, y, z, k)
    }[a]
def addition(x, y):
    return float(x) + float(y)
def subtraction(x, y):
    return float(x) - float(y)
def multiplication(x, y):
    return float(x) * float(y)
def division(x, y):
    return float(x) / float(y)
def modulo(x, y):
    return float(x) % float(y)
def secondPower(x):
    return math.pow(float(x),2.0)
def power(x, y):
    return math.pow(float(x),float(y))
def secondRadix(x):
    return math.sqrt(float(x))
def magic(x, y, z, k):
    l = float(x) + float(k)
    m = float(y) + float(z)
    return (l / m) + 1.0
#try:
#    control(a, x, y, z, k)
#except ValueError:
#    print("This operation is not supported for given input parameters")

import sys
out=None

try:
#    out = control("MAGIC", 2, 3, 4, 5)
#    control(a, x, y, z, k)
#    control(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
#    control("MAGIC", 2, 0, 0, 5)
    control("MAGIC", 2, '3', 'x', 5)
    pass
except ValueError:
    print("This operation is not supported for given input parameters")
except KeyError:
    print(f"Problem: 'a' is not one of 'ADDITION', 'SUBTRACTION', and some other ones (see code) ")
except:
    print("An unexpected Error occurred. The program code need to be fixed.")
    print(sys.exc_info())
else:
    print("See the result below:")
finally:
    print("    > here 'finally:' of the try/except block")

print(f'{out=}')
```

The code above exits in all of the cases with Exit code 0 instead of failing and raising an Exception.

To improve the code even more you should add an `except NameError:` block to it to handle a case you are aware of instead of stating that an unexpected Error occured.