# I have this error in all my programs and I can't resolve it. It is called NameError

Tags: python, nameerror

when I run my prgram, it ask me argument, and when I give argument, it displays this : `NameError: name 'number1' is not defined`

My code :

```
import random

trial = 1

numbers = [
    random.randint(1, 5),
    random.randint(1, 5),
    random.randint(1, 5),
    random.randint(1, 5)
]

see_numbers = [
        "?",
        "?",
        "?",
        "?"
]

def start(number1, number2, number3, number4):
    print(numbers)
    print(see_numbers)
    print('')

    number1 = int(input('Entrez un premier chiffre : '))
    number2 = int(input('Entrez un second chiffre : '))
    number3 = int(input('Entrez un troisième chiffre : '))
    number4 = int(input('Entrez un dernier chiffre : '))
    game(number1, number2, number3, number4)

def game(number1, number2, number3, number4, trial):

    combination = [
        number1,
        number2,
        number3,
        number4
    ]

    detect()

    if numbers == combination:
        print('')
        print('Bravo, vous avez gagné !')
        print('Nombre de tentatives : ')
    while combination != numbers:
        detect()
        trial += 1
        print('Retentez votre chance !')
        detect()
        game()

def detect(number1, number2, number3, number4):
    if number1 == numbers[0]:
        see_numbers.insert(number1, see_numbers[0])
        del see_numbers[1]

    if number2 == numbers[1]:
        see_numbers.insert(number1, see_numbers[1])
        del see_numbers[2]

    if number3 == numbers[2]:
        see_numbers.insert(number1, see_numbers[2])
        del see_numbers[3]

    if number4 == numbers[3]:
        see_numbers.insert(number1, see_numbers[3])
        del see_numbers[4]
    print(see_numbers)

start(number1, number2, number3, number4)
```

Comment: number1, number2, number3 and number4 should be declared before passing them to `start()` function in the last line of your code sample.

Comment: if in `start(number1, number2, number3, number4)`, number1, numbe2, number3, number4 are from list `numbers` you could use: `start(*numbers)`

Comment: Your next problem will probably be that you call the "game" method with 4 arguments, but it expects 5 (trial).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NameError : name "a" is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33745649/nameerror-name-a-is-not-defined)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the four variables `number1`..`number4` aren't defined when you call `start` via the line:

```
start(number1, number2, number3, number4)
```

The parameters you're passing to `start` aren't needed.  `start` doesn't use them at all.  So the cleanest fix would be to get rid of those 4 parameters by changing the definition of the `start` method to:

```
def start():
    ...
```

and then call it like this:

```
start()
```